# Note in the corner of a LaTeX document

Tags: header-footer, marginpar

I would like to put a small note in the upper right corner of my LaTeX document to put my initials for instance.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use the `background` package or the `eso-pic` package.

Comment: Or something with TikZ and overlay such as shown here: http://texample.net/tikz/examples/exam-sheet/

Answer (score 4):

From the `background` package documentation,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[placement=top,angle=0,%
color=black!40,scale=4,hshift=60,vshift=-5]{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={-\thepage-}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now using the `esp-pic` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
 \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{-1cm}{%
    \hspace*{0.9\paperwidth}%
    \huge-\thepage-%
    }
 }
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

In short, just do a quick search here with regards to background and you will find lots of examples.